# Font weight not working

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am having a problem getting the lighter font weights to work. I have font with all the weights I want to use on my computer yet it won't work. I found that A lot of fonts wont work with lighter weights. Whats going on?

https://jsfiddle.net/ywr2ks1p/

```css
p{
  font-family: museo sans;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
  hello I am some text
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: how did you decide that font weight don't work? I tried it with 700 and it is bolder as expected.

Comment: seems working perfectly !

Comment: Is that font weight supported by that font?

Comment: @Mohammed sorry but it's not at all

Comment: @Albzi How can I find this out?

Comment: Looks like it is but do you have that version too? https://typekit.com/fonts/museo-sans

Comment: @Albzi Yeah I have tried Adobe Typekit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I put 600 or more, it becomes bold, as expected. Perhaps if I were to install a thin weight version of the font the lower ones would work. in lieu of that, the browser just defaults to normal or bold.

[From Mozilla CSS Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight?v=example):

> If the exact weight given is unavailable, then the following heuristic is used to determine the weight actually rendered:
>
> - If a weight greater than 500 is given, the closest available darker weight is used (or, if there is none, the closest available lighter
>     weight).
> - If a weight less than 400 is given, the closest available lighter weight is used (or, if there is none, the closest available darker
>     weight).
> - If a weight of exactly 400 is given, then 500 is used. If 500 is not available, then the heuristic for font weights less than 400 is
>     used.
> - If a weight of exactly 500 is given, then 400 is used. If 400 is not available, then the heuristic for font weights less than 400 is
>     used.
>
> This means that for fonts that provide only normal and bold, 100-500
>   are normal, and 600-900 are bold.

Edit: looks like it does support lighter weights

Answer (score 0):

check font family. Few of them will show normal weight till 500. E.g. font-family: Rubik, sans-serif; will not show much difference when weight is till 500